# Pinterest like Grid in Android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, pinterest

I want to build a grid like the one in Pinterest app on Android.

I started extending an `AdapterView<ListAdapter>` but I cannot make many things working (for example the overscroll effect) so, after abandoning the idea to extend `AbsListView`, now I am starting thinking it is better to extend a `ListView` and override the `layoutChildren()` method.

What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: > AntipodalWall is an standalone library designed to provide a so called "masonry" grid layout for Android (much like Pinterest app). Check this project [AntipodalWall](https://github.com/expilu/AntipodalWall)

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Comment: The solution is that I am creating a custom AdapterView component. I will share the component on github, when it will be completed.

Comment: Thanks, please post your great code here

Comment: It will take a while because I cannot find good tutorials about creating AdapterView except one from Sony Ericsson that lacks many features.

Comment: @Matroska Did you find out any good solution?

Comment: In my projects I'm using: https://github.com/GDG-Korea/PinterestLikeAdapterView It's very **easy** to use it and it's memory consumption **efficient** ![Looks like that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ5AG.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We won’t be needing any external library for this as Android’s native RecyclerView makes implementing a Pinterest masonry layout simply by changing the RecyclerView’s Layout Manager

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Cool. it's Very easy ,but margin on my LinearLayout didn’t seem to work. So here’s a quick fix.

```
SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(16);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```

SpacesItemDecoration class:

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private final int mSpace;

public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
    this.mSpace = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = mSpace;
    outRect.right = mSpace;
    outRect.bottom = mSpace;

    // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
        outRect.top = mSpace;
    }
}
```

[Github link of example](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Masonry)

[image: my final Results]

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this by copying and updating Android's StaggeredGridView. https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView . Seems to work great for creating the effect you are looking for. Before this I went down the rabbit hole of copying Android's source to a separate library (which I got working) until I saw the now experimental StaggeredGridView. It is much simpler than my old "BrickView" library project so I replaced it.

Comment: the StaggeredGridView has many issues, and they can be found easily by rotating the screen after some scrolling. i suggest using a different library. i've posted a new suggestion if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by small change to existing recyclerview and it's adapter

Change to be done are :
1.In you Activity / Frgament

```
uploadMediaAdapter = new UploadMediaAdapter(getActivity(),mediaArrayList);    
rv_uploaded.setAdapter(uploadMediaAdapter);
int spanCount = 2;
rv_uploaded.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(spanCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

2.Your Recyclerview list item is :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dim_5"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dim_5"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_prev_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_progress_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8th August 2019"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_17"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            />

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

By doing this you can achieve what you are looking for!